# Merge 2 Files (audio and Video), with BITC and watermark in FFMPEG

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, watermark

I need to write ffmpeg profile to merge to merge video and audio files, and swap audio in video file from audio file, add BITC , and implement watermark from network location.
Can do it separately, but as I`m not FFMPEG expert, hard for me to combine all of above together.
Any advise would be appreciate.
Best regards all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) filter for the watermark and the [drawtext](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) filter for the burnt-in timecode:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v:0]drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/TTF/DejaVuSansMono.ttf:timecode='01\:23\:45\:00':r=25:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=h-text_h-20:fontsize=20:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxborderw=4:boxcolor=black[bg];[1][bg]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-12:format=auto[v]" -map "[v]" -map 1:a -shortest output.mp4
```

Comment: with removing [0] from filter complex (ffmpeg complain about to much inputs for drawtext) it`s exactly what i wanted.
Massive thanks and best regards Illogan!!! :)

Comment: Again, Thank you and best regards :)